# Dont allow password field to copy

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, jstl

I have this field:

```
<form:label path="password"><spring:message code="label.password"/></form:label>
 <form:password path="password" id="password"/>
```

Now what can I do to make sure this password field value cannot be copied?

Answer (score 6):

In (almost) all conformant browsers, `input`s that are `type="password"` should not have any copy functionality.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/6BUGx/

Comment: I am able to copy it, am using Mozilla-firefox

Comment: and second i cant use input type="passowrd" , i have to use <form:password path="password" id="password"/>

Comment: when i copied it out of firefox 3.6.22 it came up as `●●●●●●`

Comment: +1, I didn't actually know that @Daniel, Thanks! (is this the same for webkit?)

Comment: It should be. Otherwise, it would be a huge security hole.

Comment: @Romi: you can copy it, but you cannot paste the original value. You get the asterisks or bullets.

Comment: ok, i got. actualy it was a bug by tester. and what i thought that password should not be copied, not even in asterisks or bullets.

Answer (score 2):

Just put,

```
<input type="password" value="" />
```